# How do I manipulate the global environment inside a function in R?

Tags: r

I'd like to remove all the objects from my current environment except two of them, something like this

```
rm(list=setdiff(ls(),c("current_object_a","current_object_b")))
```

but I'd like to call it within a function. If I do it now, nothing happens because I'm deleting the environment variables inside the function, not the global environment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to specify the environment to both `ls` and `rm`.

```
rm(list = setdiff(ls(globalenv()),
                  c("current_object_a", "current_object_b")),
   pos = globalenv())
```

But, really, why do you want to do this? Deleting things out of the global environment from within a function seems like a Bad Thing.

Comment: +1 for recognizing that `ls` needs to have `globalenv()` specified also

Comment: I have a set of R files in a lib directory and I want my environment to reflect changes inside lib. If I rename a function I want to remove the old name, so I delete all the objects except the rm function and the source_dir function (which loads the lib directory) and I load them again calling rf() (refresh). Is there a better way of doing this?

    rf <- function(reset=FALSE, except=NULL){
        if (reset){
            rm(list=setdiff(ls(globalenv()),c("source_dir","rf",except)), pos=globalenv())
        }
        source_dir("my/path/to/lib/")
    }

Comment: I'd love to know if there's a better way

Comment: I would create a new environment, attach that to the search path, and then do all your manipulations within that environment. Effectively, you are making your own space to control, so you can add to (and destroy in) there with impunity. Being on the search path, you can still access those objects without having to specify the environment.

Comment: @BrianDiggs and that's exactly how `devtools::load_all` works

Answer (score 6):

You can specify the environment with either the `pos` or `envir` argument

```
rm(list=setdiff(ls(pos=globalenv()),
                c("current_object_a","current_object_b")), 
   pos=globalenv())
```

---

From `?rm`

> The ‘pos’ argument can specify the environment from which to
>        remove the objects in any of several ways: as an integer (the
>        position in the ‘search’ list); as the character string name of an
>        element in the search list; or as an ‘environment’ (including
>        using ‘sys.frame’ to access the currently active function calls).
>        The ‘envir’ argument is an alternative way to specify an
>        environment, but is primarily there for back compatibility.